# How to use key marker in ListObjectVersions, AWS S3 Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am working on a task to delete all the PDF document versions given their document key(Unique for each PDF) using AWS Java SDK.

Other developers have integrated the download code like below

```
final GetObjectRequest request = GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(documentKey).versionId(version).build();
            return client.getObject(request);
```

After searching a bit I found this code to delete single version :-

```
DeleteObjectRequest request = DeleteObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName)
                .key(documentKey).versionId(version).build();

        DeleteObjectResponse resp = client.deleteObject(request);
```

**Main question** :- How do I get all versions of single documentKey ?

I found ListObjectVersions on
below URL but It accepts a key-marker and not the actual key

> key-marker Specifies the key to start with when listing objects in a
> bucket.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectVersions.html

I am just worried if I don't use this properly I might end up deleting something else in Prod.

Edit :- All the PDFs are stored at root level in S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectVersions.html):

> **key-marker**
>
> Specifies the key to start with when listing objects in a bucket.

This means by specifying key-marker, you're just *starting* listing objects at the specified key.  ListObjectVersions can and will continue listing objects past the specified key.

Further in the documentation:

> **prefix**
>
> Use this parameter to select only those keys that begin with the specified prefix.

In other words, if you pass a prefix of only the object name, it will return the versions for that object, along with all objects that start with that prefix.

So, you can specify either the prefix of the target object key, or the key marker, but you will need still need to filter in either event to ensure you don't include other objects.